# VS Code multiple find all references

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, find all references will display the result in the sidebar, and a new find will always overwrite the previous find. How may I keep multiple find all reference sessions at the same time?

For search I have search editor which each occupies an independent tab, is there something similar for find all references?

Comment: relevant Github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148558

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you are looking for... but when you delete the current result you get a history of your last searches for references. Along with a button to rescan.

It's convenient to flip through different searches but you can not compare two different results at a glance.

[image: delete button]